# Get rid of permanent positions from job alert emails

Tags: bug, status-deferred, email, stack-overflow-jobs

In my Job matching preferences I've checked "Temporary contract" alone. However I receive email alerts about permanent positions. I do not want a permanent position and I believe that might be a bug.

As a workaround I'll try to opt out job emails in user/preferences for the time being. However if that issue can be fixed, I'd be interested in subscribing again for contract only email alerts.

Answer (score 11):

This is not so much of a bug as an omitted feature. When job matches were first implemented full time/contract/internship were never considered to be part of the algorithm. At some point they ended up in the preferences screen and the algorithm used by the candidate-facing search wasn't updated to include these things.

Right now that data is used to match your CV (if you have one) in our employer product candidate search.

Sadly it isn't as simple as just adding it to the algorithm directly; not all of our jobs have this data and we don't have a categorisation for 'Internship'. For those reasons I've marked this as [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) and we'll add it to our plans for job matching.

In the meantime you can perform a search for contract jobs [contract](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?type=contract) and subscribe to the results of that search to get what you're looking for.

Comment: "it's not a bug but a feature" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undocumented_feature#cite_ref-2

Comment: Hmmm... "not all of our jobs have this data", namely whether it's a permanent or contract opportunity. Wouldn't this seem to be, like, a rather important characteristic?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik sure, but not all jobs can be characterized as either permanent or contract. E.g. internships. We're working on extending the categories and making sure employers always specify the job type, but we still have older listings where we can't force the issue.